# What's the difference between .py and .txt for an Interpreter in python?

Tags: python, interpreter

I found this fact Interesting , The interpreter seems to be working fine with `python ex1.txt` , though It should have been **ex1.py** . What may be the reason for this ? Is there any documentation on this type of behaviour . The ex1.py or ex1.txt are the having the same `print "hello"`, will this change if I have any code change . What may be some conditions in which that `python ex1.txt` would not work.I have googled it and found nothing good .

Comment: I don't think it make much difference about file suffix. Python just opens a file, whatever it's called.  On windows you might get a file association between .py and python.exe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There should be no difference once the Python has been launched; that is, the interpreter itself does not handle Python source-code differently depending on the source file's extension.

However, the `.py` extension has special meaning for the `import` statement, which looks for *modules*. A module is (generally) either a text file with a `.py` extension (though it may be precompiled as `.pyc`) or a directory containing a file named `__init__.py`. (The `imp` module provides a workaround for importing files without the `.py` extension. Also, in Python 3, the  `__init__.py` file technically isn't necessary.)

Additionally, in Windows (though *not* in Linux!) a file's extension determines what program is used to launch the file; when Python is first installed, you are (for, I believe, most versions of the Python installer) prompted to choose whether or not to associate the `.py` extension with Python files. This means that when you double-click on a `.py` file, it will be launched using Python (equivalent to `Python <filename>.py` at the command line).

In Linux (and in fact in any *NIX-style environment, even Cygwin on Windows), file extensions do not have this special meaning whereby the operating system itself associates a particular action with a particular extension; thus, it's not uncommon on Linux to see scripts written in Python (or other scripting language) that have *no* file extension, thus making the look (and behave) more like a simple command. This idiom makes use of the "shebang" notation at the beginning of a file (`#!/usr/bin/python` or similar) to indicate that Python should be called to interpret the file. Thus, in a *NIX-style shell, to make a new command called `foo` written in Python, simply implement the command in the file `foo`, put `#!/usr/bin/python` at the beginning of the file, and put the file somewhere on your `$PATH` (such as in `~/bin`).

Comment: Your first answer has First Paragraph! Then your first edit has second one added! Then third and fourth? Srsly? I wonder where this energy comes to guys like you to help the community. Hats off!

Comment: @Vamsi Just, you know, distracting myself before bed.

Comment: It's mid noon in India, Nice of you btw :)

Comment: @Vamsi You're welcome. You can mark this as the accepted answer if you feel it adequately addresses your question.

Answer (score 3):

The `.py` extension is a convention. You can, in fact, invoke the interpreter on any file. In some cases, however, keeping with the convention is important. For example, if you write a module (something that you `import`) then the interpreter won't "guess" that your python source code is hiding in a `.txt` file. It will search only files that adhere to the conventional naming.

Answer (score 2):

Extensions are more like recommendations. There are generally two types of files - binary and ASCII. Binary files are pretty much just ones and zeroes, and are usually executable, but not editable. Binary files include something like a .docx file, because even though you can open it in Microsoft Word (which can decode the binary content), opening it in notepad would just result in garbage. ASCII files, (like .txt and .py files) are editable by something like notepad, and this is what gives us the ability to write code or text in them with many editors. The extension for these files, and any other file, has only one purpose - to tell your computer how to open it. That's why you can set applications to open .py and .txt files separately. However, at their core, these are both still ASCII files. As long as the python interpreter (or any compiler) can read that ASCII data, it can run it. The extension is just to indicate the type of contents to the user and the computer. The .py extension also helps Python indicate additional files for importing, which is why we usually need it for large programs.